# How to insert current date and time to SQL Server table that has a column with DateTime type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, .net-core

I'm working in my ASP.NET Core project and trying to add current registration date and time when a new user is registered. I used the following codes for this purpose. This is a part of registration ActionResult:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var user = new AppUser() {
    department = registerModel.department,
        creationDate = registerModel.creationDate = currentDate,
        isAdmin = registerModel.isAdmin,
        isManager = registerModel.isManager,
        isActive = registerModel.isActive,
        canEdit = registerModel.canEdit,
        canDelete = registerModel.canDelete,
        canSendMessage = registerModel.canSendMessage,
        canSeeNotification = registerModel.canSeeNotification
};
```

When I press the register button, the following error is shown:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidCastException: The field of type System.DateTime must be a
> string, array or ICollection type.
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute.IsValid(object
> value)

How can I produce the format SQL Server accepts while keeping that object as DateTime object?

Updated:

```
public class AppUser: IdentityUser < int > {
        [Display(Name = "Department")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter depertment")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string department {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Display(Name = "Creation date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public DateTime creationDate {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool isAdmin {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool isManager {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool isActive {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool canEdit {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool canDelete {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool canSendMessage {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [Required]
        //[Range(0, 1)]
        public bool canSeeNotification {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Comment: Do you use a Code First or Database First approach?

Comment: @DannyBoy I'm using CodeFirst.

Comment: Which .NET Core vertsion are you using? Could you also please provide your model code for that property? Try Serges answer bellow also. :D

Comment: Can you post AppUser class pls?

Comment: I updated the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
creationDate  = currentDate,
isAdmin = registerModel.isAdmin,
...
```